# Bootstrap responsive menu unable to open submenus

Tags: wordpress, submenu

After integrating a CSS/xHTML theme into wordpress, the bootstrap responsive menu no longer opens submenus when viewed on a mobile browser: http://d.pr/i/HrBg

1. Wordpress Theme (submenu not working): http://gtglobalcorp.com
2. Original CSS/xHTML (submenu working): http://ev.to/coded

Do you happen to know why?

Answer (score 0):

In the mobile menu, all your href attributes are hashtags.

What we have here is either a loop that isn't outputting the right markup or a Wordpress Mobile menu that's different from the Wordpress Default menu.

Without knowing the architecture of the theme, this problem can not be diagnosed further.

[image: broken menu]